# Apache, Node, .htaccess

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, content-type, mod-proxy

I have an apache webserver listening on port 80. With apache, a PHP/MySQL system based on Zend framework. And I also have a node server listening on port 3000.

When a client sends a request, always on port 80, it's therefore first handled by apache. I would like to apply the following rules before treating the request:

```
if content-type is "application/json" then
    use apache web server
else if content-type is "application/zend" then
    use apache web server
else
    use node server
```

Here content-type is sent in the request headers. Content-type "application/zend" is a custom content-type to say that, for this type of particular request, we don't want to use node server (I need this for some reasons).

I've tried to modify httpd-vhosts.conf with

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

But that's of course not enough as not everything should be handled by the node server (listening on port 3000). Hence some rules should be added. But I'm unsure where/how. I also tried to change the .htaccess file, but not sure how either.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: What is the apache version

Comment: Hi! The version is Apache/2.4.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (in `.conf` file):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-type} !=application/json
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-type} !=application/zend
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Keep in mind that this might carry a performance penalty, and if most of your requests end on node, we should perhaps search for better solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working. I just had to change the last line to: RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P] (without the slash before %{REQUEST_URI}). I take into account your comment about performances.